# Removing stop words from tokenized text using NLTK: TypeError

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, token, stop-words

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import PunktSentenceTokenizer
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
import re
import time

txt = input()

snt_tkn = sent_tokenize(txt)

wrd_tkn = [word_tokenize(s) for s in snt_tkn]

stp_wrd = set(stopwords.words("english"))

flt_snt = [w for w in wrd_tkn if not w in stp_wrd]

print(flt_snt)
```

returns the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "compiler.py", line 19, in 
    flt_snt = [w for w in wrd_tkn if not w in stp_wrd]
  File "compiler.py", line 19, in 
    flt_snt = [w for w in wrd_tkn if not w in stp_wrd]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I'd like to know, if possible, how to return the tokenized text with stop words removed without editing `wrd_tkn`.

Answer (score 2):

The error says that `list` is unhasahble. You might try to make it hashable, but lists are not hashable because they are mutable. Try to convert a list to a tuple that is not mutable and that is hashable. It can be done by constructor function

```
immutable_list = tuple(some_list)
```

Comment: Ok, I've tried this set conversion a number of ways. The problem is that it changes the order of the items (the tokenized words). I'd like them to remain in the same order.

Comment: Also, and I'm really confused by this, the stop words aren't being removed.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, the resolution is the following:

change

```
flt_snt = [w for w in wrd_tkn if not w in stp_wrd]
```

to

```
flt_snt = [[w for w in s if not w in stp_wrd]for s in wrd_tkn]
```